# How to create custom sub-domain for SAAS application built using asp.net

Tags: saas

How do i offer  sub domains to clients?

For example, my website URL is http:www.example.com whenever the user signup i want to offer them url like company.example.com which should load files/contents from /app directory of the website.

And later i want them to choose their own domain/sub-domain via CNAME, so that they can have URL like clients.mywebsite.com

I want to do this in asp.net and IIS server and of course everything happens automatically.

And i want to keep URL structure same.., that is company.example.com/login, company.example.com/accounts, company.example.com/files/style.css though these files are located inside /app directory i want them to be accessed like this.